# Maximize source rectangle to fit destination rectangle with different units

Tags: geometry

I hope I have phrased my question correctly.
I am a programmer and I am stuck on a math problem since a couple of days. I work with google maps and coordinates. Basically, I need to give google maps the "region" I want to display (source). It's a coordinate and a delta of both latitude en longitude, which makes a rectangle in the world map. I also display an overlay onto it that is also set by one of those region that I can't modify. On top of this, there is the screen width and height that I also can't modify (destination). My goal is to calculate the maximum deltas that I can display considering the aspect ratio of the screen and the overlay deltas, ultimately hiding the map under my overlay and cropping part of it. [Here's what I am trying to explain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gDNM.png) (Overlay is in red and screen is the black dotted lines) I can't find any answers since the rectangle are not using the same units and I am trying to resize the source and not the destination. It is also my first question on here, don't be too harsh please :).

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. There are three rectangles (source, screen, overlay) and I can't really tell from your picture which is which. If you could draw a picture with the final configuration and the various dimensions maybe someone can help.